# Where can i find documentation or any info on how to use/what is CV_MAT_MAGIC_VAL?

Tags: c, opencv

I looked all over google for an hour but nothing came up for CV_MAT_MAGIC_VAL ive seen it used in typedef structs for cvMat and in  declaring types for matrices created with cvCreateMat i/e here the documentation states

```
  struct CvMat

A multi-channel dense matrix.

int type

    CvMat signature (CV_MAT_MAGIC_VAL) plus type of the elements. Type of the matrix elements can be retrieved using CV_MAT_TYPE macro:

    int type = CV_MAT_TYPE(matrix->type);

    For description of possible matrix elements, see Mat.
```

but what is a signature...i could use a quick explanation of this part `CvMat signature (CV_MAT_MAGIC_VAL) plus type of the elements.`  or if you can post an online resource too so others like myself wont be stuck without info on this part of opencv ...i do know that `CV_MAT_TYPE` gets the matrix type though...

Comment: This doesn't look like C to me. Is it C++?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt  no i got it from c documentation http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvmat#cvmat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is:

1) You quoted the documentation:

[OpenCV Basic C Structures and Operations](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html).

2) It's defined in cxtypes.h: `#define CV_MAT_MAGIC_VAL    0x42420000`.

3) As the documentation says, it's part of the header in a CV "multi-channel dense matrix".  If you see the magic number, you're confident the rest of record is probably OK, and you can start accessing individual elements.  Each of which have their own CV_MAT_TYPE.

'Hope that helps..

Comment: not sure i understand "you're confident the rest of record is probably OK" if u got a sec would you mind making your explanation a little more basic still kinda new to c/opencv

Comment: ok to refine my question....i saw how its used in the header files ....but can i use it in every day code...or how would i access it or try to access it after i create the CvMat struct.